# Why my stream is unlocked before I do it myself?

Tags: c#, .net, stream, filestream

I have a text file. Several processes can simultaneously try to read and edit this file. I have a problem with `FileStream.Unlock()` method:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

static class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var fileName = @"c:\temp\data.txt";

        // Content of the 'c:\temp\data.txt' file:
        // Hello!
        // The magic number is 000. :)))
        // Good luck...

        using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, 
            FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
        {
            using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
            {
                var value = 0;
                Console.Write("New value [0-999]: ");
                while(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value))
                {
                    var prevPosition = stream.Position;
                    stream.Position = 28;
                    var data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(value.ToString());
                    try
                    {
                        stream.Lock(stream.Position, data.LongLength);
                        Console.WriteLine("Data locked. Press any key for continuation...");
               Console.ReadKey();
     stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                        stream.Flush();
                        // I get the Exception here: The segment already unlocked.
                        stream.Unlock(stream.Position, data.LongLength);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
                    }
                    stream.Position = prevPosition;
                    Console.Write("New value: ");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why my stream is unlocked before I do it myself?

Comment: Btw .Lock is of no use if there are multiple processes acting on the underlying file, its for threads in the current process only.

Comment: @AlexK. No, you are not right: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.lock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Side note, that UnLock should be inside a finally block

Comment: @HenkHolterman you are right. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is `stream.Position` is advanced after you locked the file (because you write to it), and you use `stream.Position` (which is now different) to unlock a file. In result - you are trying to unlock not the same range you locked. Instead, save `stream.Position`:

```
var position = stream.Position; // < save
stream.Lock(position, data.LongLength);
Console.WriteLine("Data locked. Press any key for continuation...");
stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); // < this changes stream.Position, breaking your old logic
stream.Flush();
// I get the Exception here: 
// The blocking of the segment already taken off.
stream.Unlock(position, data.LongLength); // < now you unlock the same range
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe when you Write, the Stream.Position changes.